# Soft Lockup - CPU Stuck qemu-system-x86

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, openstack, qemu

I have a system running:
* openstack icehouse
* Linux 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux(Ubuntu 3.13.0-48.80-generic 3.13.11-ckt16)

Suddenly the server freeze and the log that in the system are

```
[13551520.909322] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 23s! [migration/4:76]
[13551520.909357] Modules linked in: vhost_net vhost macvtap macvlan nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_mac xt_physdev veth ipt_MASQUERA
DE iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle xt_tcpudp bridge ip6table_filter ip6_ta
bles iptable_filter ip_tables ebtable_nat ebtables x_tables nbd ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_sa ib_mad ib_core ib_addr iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_is
csi openvswitch gre vxlan ip_tunnel dm_crypt usb_storage gpio_ich joydev dm_multipath scsi_dh intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp crct10dif_pclmul c
rc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd serio_raw ipmi_si sb_edac edac_core mei_me mei lpc_ich shpchp mac_hid k
vm_intel kvm 8021q garp stp mrp llc lp parport btrfs xor hid_generic usbhid hid raid6_pq libcrc32c ses enclosure ast syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt ttm psmouse drm_kms
_helper isci drm igb ahci libsas dca libahci ptp pps_core scsi_transport_sas i2c_algo_bit megaraid_sas wmi
[13551520.909377] CPU: 4 PID: 76 Comm: migration/4 Tainted: G D W 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu
[13551520.909378] Hardware name: ASUSTek Computer INC. RS720-E7-RS12-E/Z9PE-D16 Series, BIOS 5302 11/08/2013
[13551520.909379] task: ffff881029391800 ti: ffff88102938c000 task.ti: ffff88102938c000
[13551520.909386] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff810f61cb>] [<ffffffff810f61cb>] multi_cpu_stop+0x6b/0xf0
[13551520.909387] RSP: 0018:ffff88102938dd98 EFLAGS: 00000293
[13551520.909388] RAX: ffffffff8180ae00 RBX: ffff88103fc934c0 RCX: 0000000000007c34
[13551520.909389] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff881083bd37b8
[13551520.909390] RBP: ffff88102938ddb8 R08: 0000000000000282 R09: 0000000000000001
[13551520.909391] R10: 000000000000b590 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff88102938dd20
[13551520.909392] R13: ffff88035499e000 R14: ffffffff81098235 R15: ffff88035499e000
[13551520.909394] FS: 0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88103fc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[13551520.909395] CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[13551520.909396] CR2: 00007f0206b09000 CR3: 00000008ee4ad000 CR4: 00000000000427e0
[13551520.909397] Stack:
[13551520.909401] ffff881083bd37e0 ffff88103fc8de20 ffff88103fc8de28 ffff881083bd37b8
[13551520.909404] ffff88102938de78 ffffffff810f63de 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[13551520.909408] ffff88103fc934c0 ffff881024f38700 0000000000000000 ffff88103fc934c0
[13551520.909409] Call Trace:
[13551520.909413] [<ffffffff810f63de>] cpu_stopper_thread+0x7e/0x150
[13551520.909418] [<ffffffff817254a1>] ? __schedule+0x381/0x7d0
[13551520.909423] [<ffffffff810928cf>] smpboot_thread_fn+0xff/0x1b0
[13551520.909426] [<ffffffff810927d0>] ? SyS_setgroups+0x180/0x180
[13551520.909429] [<ffffffff8108b5b2>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
[13551520.909432] [<ffffffff8108b4e0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
[13551520.909436] [<ffffffff81731f0c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[13551520.909439] [<ffffffff8108b4e0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
[13551520.909459] Code: 31 f6 31 d2 eb 23 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 83 fb 03 75 05 45 84 ed 75 66 f0 41 ff 4c 24 24 74 26 89 da 83 fa
 04 74 3d f3 90 <41> 8b 5c 24 20 39 d3 74 f0 83 fb 02 75 d7 fa 66 66 90 66 66 90
[13551520.971633] [<ffffffff81184b76>] try_to_unmap_one+0x36/0x480
[13551520.973089] [<ffffffff81186556>] ? rmap_walk+0x186/0x210
[13551520.974528] [<ffffffff81185d77>] try_to_unmap_anon+0xa7/0x120
[13551520.975958] [<ffffffff81185e3d>] try_to_unmap+0x4d/0x60
[13551520.977372] [<ffffffff811a88fe>] migrate_pages+0x43e/0x780
[13551520.978769] [<ffffffff81171bb0>] ? isolate_freepages_block+0x310/0x310
[13551520.980165] [<ffffffff81172bb9>] compact_zone+0x299/0x410
[13551520.981549] [<ffffffff81172dbe>] compact_zone_order+0x8e/0xd0
[13551520.982916] [<ffffffff81173111>] try_to_compact_pages+0x101/0x180
[13551520.984279] [<ffffffff8171c1a3>] __alloc_pages_direct_compact+0xac/0x196
[13551520.985641] [<ffffffff81159160>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x760/0xb80
[13551520.986971] [<ffffffff81199d9a>] alloc_pages_vma+0x9a/0x140
[13551520.988267] [<ffffffff811ad62b>] do_huge_pmd_anonymous_page+0x10b/0x3f0
[13551520.989540] [<ffffffff8136aa2f>] ? __rb_insert_augmented+0x8f/0x1f0
[13551520.990779] [<ffffffff81179c48>] handle_mm_fault+0x198/0xf10
[13551520.991984] [<ffffffff8117ec97>] ? vma_link+0xb7/0xc0
[13551520.993153] [<ffffffff8172d534>] __do_page_fault+0x184/0x560
[13551520.994289] [<ffffffff8118166e>] ? do_mmap_pgoff+0x34e/0x3d0
[13551520.995387] [<ffffffff8116bcf9>] ? vm_mmap_pgoff+0x99/0xc0
[13551520.996443] [<ffffffff8172d92a>] do_page_fault+0x1a/0x70
[13551520.997476] [<ffffffff8107aaa7>] ? sigprocmask+0x57/0x90
[13551520.998481] [<ffffffff81729d68>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
[13551520.999462] Code: 55 48 89 e5 b8 00 00 02 00 f0 0f c1 07 89 c2 c1 ea 10 66 39 c2 75 02 5d c3 83 e2 fe 0f b7 f2 b8 00 80 00 00 eb 0c
 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f3> 90 83 e8 01 74 0a 0f b7 0f 66 39 ca 75 f1 5d c3 66 66 66 90

[13551521.013327] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 22s! [qemu-system-x86:14068]
[13551521.014492] Modules linked in: vhost_net vhost macvtap macvlan nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_mac xt_physdev veth ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle xt_tcpudp bridge ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter ip_tables ebtable_nat ebtables x_tables nbd ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_sa ib_mad ib_core ib_addr iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi openvswitch gre vxlan ip_tunnel dm_crypt usb_storage gpio_ich joydev dm_multipath scsi_dh intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd serio_raw ipmi_si sb_edac edac_core mei_me mei lpc_ich shpchp mac_hid kvm_intel kvm 8021q garp stp mrp llc lp parport btrfs xor hid_generic usbhid hid raid6_pq libcrc32c ses enclosure ast syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt ttm psmouse drm_kms
_helper isci drm igb ahci libsas dca libahci ptp pps_core scsi_transport_sas i2c_algo_bit megaraid_sas wmi
[13551521.025305] CPU: 6 PID: 14068 Comm: qemu-system-x86 Tainted: G D W 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu
[13551521.026588] Hardware name: ASUSTek Computer INC. RS720-E7-RS12-E/Z9PE-D16 Series, BIOS 5302 11/08/2013
[13551521.027894] task: ffff88109083b000 ti: ffff8810ed20a000 task.ti: ffff8810ed20a000
[13551521.029199] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff810dbf92>] [<ffffffff810dbf92>] generic_exec_single+0x82/0xb0
[13551521.030529] RSP: 0000:ffff8810ed20ba20 EFLAGS: 00000202
[13551521.031854] RAX: 0000000000000100 RBX: 0000000000000286 RCX: 0000000000000004
[13551521.033195] RDX: ffff88207fc0ce20 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000286
[13551521.034536] RBP: ffff8810ed20ba50 R08: ffff88207fc0ce08 R09: 0000000000000004
[13551521.035878] R10: ffff88207fff8f00 R11: ffffea0059bee9e0 R12: ffff8810ed20b9f0
[13551521.037224] R13: ffff88207fc0ce00 R14: 0000000000000040 R15: ffffffff813645f0
[13551521.038569] FS: 00007fbb42ffd700(0000) GS:ffff88207fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[13551521.039932] CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[13551521.041271] CR2: 00007fbb6ea50000 CR3: 00000006fc224000 CR4: 00000000000427e0
[13551521.042599] Stack:
[13551521.043897] ffff88103fc73f80 0000000000000003 0000000000000006 ffffffff81d14380
[13551521.045245] ffffffff8105c7a0 0000000000000301 ffff8810ed20bac8 ffffffff810dc0a5
[13551521.046593] ffff88207fffb040 ffff88207fff8f68 ffff88103fc77710 ffff88103fc73f80
[13551521.047954] Call Trace:
[13551521.049305] [<ffffffff8105c7a0>] ? leave_mm+0x80/0x80
[13551521.050663] [<ffffffff810dc0a5>] smp_call_function_single+0xe5/0x190
[13551521.052027] [<ffffffff8105c7a0>] ? leave_mm+0x80/0x80
[13551521.053394] [<ffffffff810dc4d6>] smp_call_function_many+0x286/0x2d0
[13551521.054765] [<ffffffff8105c7a0>] ? leave_mm+0x80/0x80
[13551521.056130] [<ffffffff8105c8f7>] native_flush_tlb_others+0x37/0x40
[13551521.057503] [<ffffffff8105cbf6>] flush_tlb_page+0x56/0xa0
[13551521.058873] [<ffffffff8118a5b8>] ptep_clear_flush+0x48/0x60
[13551521.060239] [<ffffffff81184bff>] try_to_unmap_one+0xbf/0x480
[13551521.061597] [<ffffffff81185d77>] try_to_unmap_anon+0xa7/0x120
[13551521.062947] [<ffffffff81185e3d>] try_to_unmap+0x4d/0x60
[13551521.064298] [<ffffffff811a88fe>] migrate_pages+0x43e/0x780
[13551521.065642] [<ffffffff811a7210>] ? remove_migration_pte+0x330/0x330
[13551521.066993] [<ffffffff811a9674>] migrate_misplaced_page+0xc4/0xf0
[13551521.068352] [<ffffffff81178ede>] do_numa_page+0x12e/0x1b0
[13551521.069710] [<ffffffff8117a0af>] handle_mm_fault+0x5ff/0xf10
[13551521.071075] [<ffffffff811ffc91>] ? fsnotify+0x241/0x320
[13551521.072440] [<ffffffff8172d534>] __do_page_fault+0x184/0x560
[13551521.073782] [<ffffffff811bede9>] ? do_readv_writev+0x169/0x220
[13551521.075098] [<ffffffff8118272b>] ? change_protection+0x9b/0xb0
[13551521.076393] [<ffffffff810a02c5>] ? set_next_entity+0x95/0xb0
[13551521.077663] [<ffffffff8101260b>] ? __switch_to+0x16b/0x4d0
[13551521.078916] [<ffffffffa0332504>] ? kvm_on_user_return+0x74/0x80 [kvm]
[13551521.080121] [<ffffffff8172d92a>] do_page_fault+0x1a/0x70
[13551521.081286] [<ffffffff81729d68>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
[13551521.082415] Code: 08 4c 89 ff 4c 89 23 48 89 4b 08 48 89 19 48 89 55 d0 e8 f2 d3 64 00 4c 3b 65 d0 74 23 45 85 ed 75 09 eb 0d 0f 1f
 44 00 00 f3 90 <f6> 43 20 01 75 f8 48 83 c4 08 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3
```

please advise

Comment: You've withheld a lot of information from us. Did this only happen once? Was the system ever reliable? Does it always happen the same way? Are you doing anything unusual (such as running threads with SCHED_FIFO) that could cause a CPU to get stuck? Do you know the hardware is reliable? And so on.

Comment: Do you have overcomitted CPU or RAM on this host? If not, this may be something you can safely ignore

Comment: Yes we have overcommitted CPU in the machine.

Comment: yes is there another information that you need. this is the first time it happened